# Run function on plugin upgrade

Tags: plugins

Hi a new version of a plugin I have in the repository changes the way the data is stored in the database, how can I perform a check on upgrade that automatically moves the data to the new location, so the users don't lose any of their settings and are not aware of what is happening beneath the hood?

Comment: Here's some sort of relevant info http://clark-technet.com/2010/12/wordpress-self-hosted-plugin-update-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
global $myplugin_db_version;
$myplugin_db_version = "1.0";

function myplugin_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $myplugin_db_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "myplugin";

    $installed_ver = get_option( "myplugin_db_version" );

    if( $installed_ver != $myplugin_db_version ) {

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
                id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
                name tinytext NOT NULL,
                text text NOT NULL,
                url VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY id (id));
        ";         

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

        update_option( "myplugin_db_version", $myplugin_db_version );

    }
}

function myplugin_update_db_check() {
    global $myplugin_db_version;
    if ( get_site_option( 'myplugin_db_version' ) != $myplugin_db_version) {
        myplugin_install();
    }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_update_db_check');
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if the db version is stored as a constant instead of a global variable?

Comment: There is no difference, but you need to make sure your constant is unique (avoid conflicts)