# Wordpress Update Plugin Hook/Action? Since 3.9

Tags: plugin-development, actions, upgrade

I've researched this a few times, yet my searching does not reveal much except custom code which may or may not be good WordPress practice.

As of the latest releases (WordPress 3.9 "Smith"), **has a hook been added to the plugin update process?** I'm asking because its a very basic need, yet I do not see it added to the codex (yet). If not, what is the common and best practice developers employ?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm not talking about activation, but about updating, that way, if there are changes in database or otherwise it can be addressed.

Comment: duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/run-function-on-plugin-upgrade

Comment: @drzaus answer provided there is not a good practice.

Comment: @RensTillmann asides from this being 2 years out of date anyway, the linked q/a has basically the same answer but predates this question by another 2 years, hence the 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think an action has been added. You can [look at version details](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.9) for any version and see any new actions added.

The WordPress Way to run code on plugin update is what is described [here](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2010/10/27/plugin-activation-hooks-no-longer-fire-for-updates/):

> The proper way to handle an upgrade path is to only run an upgrade procedure when you need to. Ideally, you would store a “version” in your plugin’s database option, and then a version in the code. If they do not match, you would fire your upgrade procedure, and then set the database option to equal the version in the code. This is how many plugins handle upgrades, and this is how core works as well.

and with code example [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Adding_an_Upgrade_Function):

```
function myplugin_update_db_check() {
    global $jal_db_version;
    if (get_site_option( 'jal_db_version' ) != $jal_db_version) {
        jal_install();
    }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_update_db_check' );
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll simply use that method then. WP really has to add an action for this :D

Comment: technically you're supposed to use [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook), since in most cases a plugin gets deactivated/activated whenever you update it from the admin.  Hooking to `plugins_loaded` will do your check on every page load (including frontend).  There was talk about introducing `register_update_hook`, but it was [marked as WONTFIX](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14912) a while ago.   The discussion there is helpful.

Comment: It's important to understand that a mass plugin update does NOT run activation hooks - it SHOULD, but doesn't at 3.9.2.  By "mass update" I mean an update done from the Dashboard update page.  Individual updates done from within the plugin page run the hooks just fine.

Comment: The thing is plugins can also be updated via FTP which means that the hook will not be fired in any case. That's why you need to resort to the option stored in the database.

Comment: To expand on @giraff's comment, the same is true for people who manage their code with source control like SVN or Git. Because of that, this answer *is* the best way to handle upgrades.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant but if you are looking for some hooks triggered before upgrade and after upgrade then take a look at [upgrader_pre_install](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_pre_install) respectively [upgrader_post_install](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_post_install)

Answer (score 4):

Since WordPress 3.9 you can use `upgrader_process_complete` hook.
This hook will be fire when upgrader process is complete (plugins and themes are updated).

See reference [1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete), [2](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/), [3](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.9/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L858)

Here is an example code:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test plugin 1
 * Plugin URI: https://rundiz.com
 * Description: A very simple plugin for testing. This plugin do nothing.
 * Version: 0.1.8
 * Author: Vee Winch
 * Author URI: http://rundiz.com
 * License: MIT
 * License URI: https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 * Text Domain: test-plugin1
 * Domain Path: 
 */


add_action('upgrader_process_complete', 'testplugin_upgrade_completed', 10, 2);
/**
 * Upgrader process complete.
 *
 * @see \WP_Upgrader::run() (wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php)
 * @param \WP_Upgrader $upgrader_object
 * @param array $hook_extra
 */
function testplugin_upgrade_completed(\WP_Upgrader $upgrader_object, $hook_extra)
{
    // get current plugin version. ( https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18270/41315 )
    if(!function_exists('get_plugin_data')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    }
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_data/
    $plugin_data = get_plugin_data(__FILE__);
    $plugin_version = ($plugin_data['Version'] ?? 'unknown.version');
    unset($plugin_data);

    if (
        is_array($hook_extra) && 
        array_key_exists('action', $hook_extra) && 
        $hook_extra['action'] == 'update'
    ) {
        if (
            array_key_exists('type', $hook_extra) && 
            $hook_extra['type'] == 'plugin'
        ) {
            // if updated the plugins.
            $this_plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
            $this_plugin_updated = false;
            if (array_key_exists('plugins', $hook_extra)) {
                // if bulk plugin update (in update page)
                foreach ($hook_extra['plugins'] as $each_plugin) {
                    if ($each_plugin === $this_plugin) {
                        $this_plugin_updated = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }// endforeach;
                unset($each_plugin);
            } elseif (array_key_exists('plugin', $hook_extra)) {
                // if normal plugin update or via auto update.
                if ($this_plugin === $hook_extra['plugin']) {
                    $this_plugin_updated = true;
                }
            }
            if ($this_plugin_updated === true) {
                // if this plugin is just updated.
                // do your task here.
                // DON'T process anything from new version of code here, because it will work on old version of the plugin.
                // please read again!! the code run here is not new (just updated) version but the version before that.
                file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/test.txt', 'v'.$plugin_version."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
                // set transient to let it run later.
                set_transient('testplugin_just_updated', 1);
            }
        } elseif (
            array_key_exists('type', $hook_extra) && 
            $hook_extra['type'] == 'theme'
        ) {
            // if updated the themes.
            // same as plugin, the bulk theme update will be set the name in $hook_extra['themes'] as 'theme1', 'theme2'.
            // normal update or via auto update will be set the name in $hook_extra['theme'] as 'theme1'.
        }
    }// endif; $hook_extra
}// testplugin_upgrade_completed


add_action('plugins_loaded', 'testplugin_pluginloaded');
/**
 * Run once plugin loaded (on every page load).
 */
function testplugin_pluginloaded()
{
    // get current plugin version. ( https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18270/41315 )
    if(!function_exists('get_plugin_data')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    }
    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_data/
    $plugin_data = get_plugin_data(__FILE__);
    $plugin_version = ($plugin_data['Version'] ?? 'unknown.version');
    unset($plugin_data);

    if (get_transient('testplugin_just_updated') && current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        // if it was marked in transient that this plugin just updated and current user is admin.
        // you can use new verion of code here.
        file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/test-update-by-transient.txt', 'v'.$plugin_version."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

        // your update code here.
        
        // delete transient when done to do not let this code run again.
        delete_transient('testplugin_just_updated');
    }
}// testplugin_pluginloaded
```

The `upgrader_process_complete` hook will be run with your current version of code while the plugin/theme is updating. It is not use new version.

##### Scenario

1. You have plugin version 1.0
2. You run the update page or auto update.
3. Your plugin version 2.0 will be downloaded and extract. The `upgrader_process_complete` hook will be called.
4. Your plugin version 1.0 will be run in `upgrader_process_complete` hook.
5. Once done, reload your page and the `plugins_loaded` hook will be called.
6. Your plugin version 2.0 run in `plugins_loaded` hook. (The plugin must be activated.)

These are already explained in the code I have posted from earlier (before edit) but maybe not clearly or hard to see it.

The `upgrader_process_complete` hook is created for this (please read in the reference link [3](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.9/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L858)). To run after upgrade completed.

You may use `plugins_loaded` hook with the code in accepted answer. It did work and write shorter or you may have any better idea to use with `upgrader_process_complete` hook.

The `upgrader_process_complete` hook will be work when:

1. Update via the update page.
2. Update via the plugins or themes page.
3. Update via auto update or WP Cron.

The code above doesn't work when you update plugin or theme via FTP because it can't detected transient option. In this case, the accepted answer is the only best option for you.

Comment: This hook sounds good at first, but if you check the codex, there is a warning that says it runs code from the prior version of the plugin. This is because this hook doesn't run after the entire update process. It actually runs after the download is complete and before the old version is even deleted.

Comment: @user54141 Yes, it use the code from prior version. 
That's why I use `set_transient()` to mark that this plugin is just updated and use `get_transient()` after `plugins_loaded` hook (work when reloaded page) to check if it really is just updated then run the new code. 
The `plugins_loaded` hook will work after reload page and the transient will be check that plugin is just updated. 
Once new updated code had runned, it will be delete that transient so that it can run once after plugin updated.

Comment: Since this solution ultimately checks if the plugin was updated on plugins_loaded, it's much simpler to use the selected answer which does the same thing with much less code.

Comment: @user54141 Yes, the accepted answer code is very good. I agreed. However this hook is still good for someone who may have better idea than I am to use it when upgrade plugin is done. This is what `upgrader_process_complete` hook is for.

Answer (score 2):

From the [discussion where they decided not to add a custom hook/function specific to upgrade](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14912), it sounds like "most people" (as of 4 years ago) use `register_activation_hook`, since it's called when a plugin is upgraded through the admin page; most examples I've seen since then follow that trend.

For most usage I would suggest not hooking through `plugins_loaded`, as it would get called on every page load.  The exception to this is mentioned in the discussion: upgrade paths via FTP/SVN are 'edge cases', since WP wouldn't have a mechanism to know that the plugin was changed, in which case the [previous answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144873/13122) might be more relevant.

See https://gist.github.com/zaus/c08288c68b7f487193d1 for a 'simple framework' example using [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook).

Comment: `register_activation_hook` is not guaranteed to be run on updates, see https://make.wordpress.org/core/2010/10/27/plugin-activation-hooks-no-longer-fire-for-updates/

Comment: Very much - do NOT use `plugins_loaded` - runs every load, and can be burdensome / slow.

Comment: `register_activation_hook` no longer runs on updates. That was an inconsistency they fixed. It is only triggered on plugin activations now.

Using `plugins_loaded` is recommended in the codex. It's not slow because WP makes a single query for all of the site's options and caches it, so even though you're using `get_option()` to check the version saved in the DB, it doesn't actually make a DB request. It just checks the cached request.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the [upgrader_pre_install](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_pre_install/) and [upgrader_post_install](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_post_install/) filters.

Answer (score 0):

As I happen to be searching for something related in Nov. 2023, I thought I'd offer this suggestion: the `update_plugins_{$hostname}` *filter* was introduced in WordPress version 5.8.0.

This feature only works if the plugin is using the `Update URI` header. So if you're creating a plugin, you can include the `Update URI` header at the top of the main file with the value being your JSON's endpoint. Then you'd hook into the filter replacing `{hostname}` with the host name of that URL. For example, let's say this is my custom plugin file located in `/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-plugin/my-custom-plugin.php` and I've got the top here:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Custom Plugin
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: AuRise Creative
 * Update URI: https://aurisecreative.com/update-my-custom-plugin/
 */
```

Now I could hook into the plugin updates for it to retrieve my update data (if any) for that plugin.

```
/**
 * Check for Plugin Updates
 *
 * @param array|false $update The plugin update data with the latest details. Default false.
 * @param array $plugin_data Plugin headers.
 * @param string $plugin_file Plugin filename.
 * @param string $locales Installed locales to look up translations for.
 *
 * @return array|false An associative array of update data on success. False otherwise.
 */
function prefix_check_for_plugin_updates($update, $plugin_data, $plugin_file, $locales = '')
{
    // Do stuff
    return $update;
}
add_filter('update_plugins_aurisecreative.com', 'prefix_check_for_plugin_updates', 10, 4);
```

Unfortunately, this *only* works for plugins that use the header, so most likely in premium plugins.

Sources:

- [Dev documentation for `update_plugins_{hostname}` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_plugins_hostname/)
- [Plugin Header Fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/#header-fields)
- [Announcement of "Update URI" plugin header in WordPress 5.8](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/introducing-update-uri-plugin-header-in-wordpress-5-8/) published on June 29, 2021