# Any ideas to trigger some code after plugin update?

Tags: plugin-development

I have developed a plugin, that requires to do some maintenance tasks after a certain WordPress plugin has been updated in my sites.

Currently, what I do, is to have this WP plugin on manual updates, and every time I update it manually, I run the code afterwards.

But I would like to automate this process.

Any ideas to makes this possible?

Comment: Try checking the following questions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187990/plugin-update-hook
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144870/wordpress-update-plugin-hook-action-since-3-9

Comment: note that if the plugin is updated using any method other than the updater, or your code runs but fails, maybe because it ran out of time or something else interfered, then you will have no opportunities to re-run your code. Likewise if it's a multisite and the upgrade happens from a blog where your plugin is not present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always used the `upgrader_process_complete` hook:

```
function my_plugins_update_completed( $upgrader_object, $options ) {

    // If an update has taken place and the updated type is plugins and the plugins element exists
    if ( $options['action'] == 'update' && $options['type'] == 'plugin' && isset( $options['plugins'] ) ) {
        foreach( $options['plugins'] as $plugin ) {
            // Check to ensure it's my plugin
            if( $plugin == plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) {
                // do stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'my_plugins_update_completed', 10, 2 );
```

More info in the Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/

Hope that helps

Comment: Tried it and worked great. That is what I was looking for.